# agora.io Swift Users can not connect to the same channel

Tags: swift, agora.io

I my agora account with android and it works fine . Using the same account for ios with the latest sdk, i can get users to join the a chnnael with the same ID but both user never connects, no callback when the other user logs in and no voice (managed to make it work the first time ?)

import Foundation
import AgoraRtcKit

class AgoraViewController: UIViewController {

```
var agoraKit: AgoraRtcEngineKit?
var agoraDelegate: AgoraRtcEngineDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeAgoraEngine()
    joinChannel()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    leaveChannel()
    destroyInstance()
}

func initializeAgoraEngine() {
    agoraKit = AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: "Valid Id i can give if needed", delegate: agoraDelegate)
}

func joinChannel() {
    let result = agoraKit?.joinChannel(byToken: "Token", channelId: "TestChannel2", info: nil, uid: 0, joinSuccess: {(channel, uid, elapsed) in
        
    })
    
    //result is zero as expected
}

func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didJoinedOfUid uid: UInt, elapsed: Int) {
     
  //is never called
}

func leaveChannel() {
    agoraKit?.leaveChannel(nil)
}

func destroyInstance() {
    AgoraRtcEngineKit.destroy()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For the token field, are you using a temporary token made for the correct channel name? FYI those tokens expire after 24 hours.

If you're using the 3.x SDK then everything else should be fine. It may be worth adding a call to `agoraKit?.enableVideo()`, and this project here does the bare minimum setting up from scratch, might be worth looking at:

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-iOS-SwiftPM/tree/main/Agora_SDK-Example

the other project in that repo uses Agora UIKit, which would be an easier setup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . It seemed that issue was related to delegate .No token issue at all . I used a complete different code to connect and it worked . Still don t know why it wasn't the case here .

Comment: Oh I see it now, you'll need to put `self` instead of `agoraDelegate` in the engine creation. Glad you got it working!